# Why is this an equality? Proof Assistance In C* Algebras By Murphy

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Here is the result I'm covering:

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $H$ a Hilbert space, and suppose that $\varphi: C(X) \longrightarrow B(H)$ is a unital $*$ homomorphism.  Then there exists a unique spectral measure $E$ with respect to the pair $(X,H)$ such that: $$\varphi(f) = \int_{X} f \: dE \: \: \forall \: f \in C(X).$$

Proof:  Let $x,y \in H$.  Then the map $\tau_{x,y}: C(X) \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $\tau_{x,y}(f) = \langle \varphi(f)(x),y\rangle $ is linear and $||\tau_{x,y}|| \leq ||x|| \: ||y||$.  Hence By Reisz Kakutani, there exists a unique measure $\mu_{x,y} \in M(X) = \{\mu: \Sigma(X) \longrightarrow \mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\} \: | \: \text{$\mu$ is a complex regular Borel measure with $|\mu|(X) = ||\mu|| < \infty$}\}$ such that: $$\tau_{x,y}(f) = \int_{X} f \: d\mu_{x,y} \: \: \forall f \in C(X).$$ Also we have that $||\tau_{x,y}|| = ||\mu_{x,y}||$...

My question is, why do we have that $||\tau_{x,y}|| = ||\mu_{x,y}||$?  I know from above that $$|\tau_{x,y}(1)| = |\mu_{x,y}(X)| \leq |\mu_{x,y}|(X) = ||\mu_{x,y}||$$ but I dont see how the equality is achieved unless $|\mu_{x,y}(X)| = |\mu_{x,y}|(X)$, which only would be true if $\mu_{x,y}$ was nonnegative, which we don't know.

Does $\mu_{x,y}$ being inner regular imply $|\mu_{x,y}(X)| = |\mu_{x,y}|(X)$ or something?

Comment: Instead of using the function $1$, what if you tried a function that shares the same support as $\mu_{x,y}$ and cancels out the phase/sign of $\mu_{x,y}$? It's a little sketchy, but at least intuitively we would divide the support of $\mu_{x,y}$ into small enough balls where it is approximately constant and then such a function would take the opposite phase of $\mu_{x,y}$ on each ball. To make it rigorous, I imagine you could approximate $\mu_{x,y}$ weakly by a sequence of more regular measures where this is easier to accomplish.

Comment: Doesn't it follow directly from the Riesz-Kakutani theorem? I mean that $C(X)^*$ is isometric to $M(X)$?

Comment: @KeeperOfSecrets I believe you're correct, and the author is probably referring to the Reisz **Markov**  kakutani theorem for continuous functionals on C_0(X) = C(X) here since X is Hausdorff, which solves this very cleanly.